It the following a computable function?
Suppose to have a family of computable sets $\mathcal{A} = \{A_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, then consider the function:
\begin{align*}
f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}& \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}\\
(n, m)& \longmapsto f(n,m) = \chi_{A_n}(m)
\end{align*}
where $\chi_{A_n}: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is the characteristic function of the set $A_n$. Obviously for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the function $f(n,\cdot) = \chi_{A_n}$ is computable because by assumption $A_n$ is computable. But what about $f$, is it computable? If not why? And, moreover, if not what should be the requirements on the family $\mathcal{A}$ to have it computable?

Hi, welcome to MSE. Can you think of such a family $\mathcal A$ such that knowing the function $f$ lets you solve the halting problem?

One typical sort of condition under which $f$ is computable is if the family $\mathcal A$ is uniformly computable, by which I mean there is a Turing machine which on input $n$ produces a Turing machine which decides if its input lies in $A_n$. Many "nice/explicitly constructed" families will have this property. It has a somewhat trivial feel, though - is that what you're looking for?

@IzaakvanDongen Yes, I am looking for some characterisation like that. But are there other possibilities? This condition on $\mathcal{A}$ is only a sufficient condition not also necessary right?

I believe it is actually necessary, since if $f$ is computable then $\mathcal A$ must be uniformly computable (given input $n$, return the Turing machine which, given $m$, feeds $(n, m)$ into the Turing machine computing $f$). This is sort of why it's not terribly useful/profound - it's more or less a restatement of "$f$ is computable".

Unfortunately it does not have to be computable, even when each $A_n$ is almost trivial, i.e. it is empty or singleton.
Consder any subset $B\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and define
$$A_n=\begin{cases}
\{0\} &\text{if }n\in B\\
\emptyset &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Of course each $A_n$ is computable. But then if $f$ is computable, then $B$ is computable as well. Indeed, the question "is $n\in B$?" is equivalent to the question "is $f(n,0)$ equal to $1$?" which is computable. But $B$ was arbitary, in particular I can pick a noncomputable subset. Which is a contradiction.
As for concrete condition, I can't help you with that. I don't know.
